How to use color themes/styles in menukeys package?
How to use new created themes/styles in the third/last block?, in the menukeys package

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,solutionsreseteqcounter,spanish]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[spanish,es-lcroman]{babel} % PROBLEMA, se compilo con esto da problema.
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table,x11names,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[os=win]{menukeys}
%\newcommand{\ShiftCalc}{SHIFT}

%\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
%\tcbuselibrary{listings}


\begin{document}
Testing the basic of \verb"Menukeys"

\keys{\ctrl+C} 

\menu[>]{Extras>Settings>{Units, rulers and origin}}

\menu[,]{Extras,Settings,{Units, rulers and origin}}

\directory[pathswithfolder]{C:/mame/mameroms/indy.rom}

\bigskip
Changing colors...

\changemenucolor{gray}{txt}{named}{yellow}
\changemenucolor{gray}{bg}{HTML}{0077BB}
\changemenucolor{gray}{br}{named}{orange}

\menu[>]{Extras>Settings>{Units, rulers and origin}}

\keys{\ctrl+C} 

\directory[pathswithfolder]{C:/mame/mameroms/indy.rom}

\bigskip
{\color{red} And how to changing colors using NEW CREATED styles or themes?}

\newmenucolortheme{menucores}{HTML}{005500}{00FF00}{00BB00}[550000][FF0000][BB0000]
\newmenustylesimple{menucoresstyle}{}[,]{menucores}

\menu[menucoresstyle]{Extras>Settings>{Units, rulers and origin}}

\keys{\ctrl+C}

\directory[pathswithfolder]{C:/mame/mameroms/indy.rom}

\end{documement}

And how to obtain, using a style or theme color, any similar to the next image?, with colors {005500}{00FF00}{00BB00} or any others.


Aside: With a relatively recent LaTeX installation you don't need \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} anymore as that's the standard since a few years.

You misuse the optional argument of menukeys macros: \menu[menucoresstyle] doesn't change the style, but instead specifies that the separator between items is now the string menucoresstyle (see what happens when you use \menu[menucoresstyle]{ExtrasmenucoresstyleSettingsmenucoresstyle{Units, rulers and origin}} in your MWE).
If you want to change the style of a menukeys macro you need to redefine the macro using \renewmenumacro.
Additionally, if you want to change the colour theme you could change the individual colours of the used theme as you did, but it's preferable to create a new theme and change the used style to pick that one up (you'll need to know the names of those styles). That can be done with \changemenucolortheme.
Everything combined:
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,solutionsreseteqcounter,spanish]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[spanish,es-lcroman]{babel} % PROBLEMA, se compilo con esto da problema.
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table,x11names,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[os=win]{menukeys}
%\newcommand{\ShiftCalc}{SHIFT}

%\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
%\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\renewmenumacro\directory[/]{pathswithfolder}

\newmenucolortheme{terminal}{HTML}{005500}{00BB00}{00FF00}

\begin{document}
Testing the basic of \verb"Menukeys"

\keys{\ctrl+C} 

\menu{Extras>Settings>{Units, rulers and origin}}

\menu[,]{Extras,Settings,{Units, rulers and origin}}

\directory{C:/mame/mameroms/indy.rom}

\bigskip
Changing colors...
\changemenucolortheme{menus}{terminal}
\changemenucolortheme{roundedkeys}{terminal}
\changemenucolortheme{pathswithfolder}{terminal}

\menu{Extras>Settings>{Units, rulers and origin}}

\keys{\ctrl+C} 

\directory{C:/mame/mameroms/indy.rom}

\bigskip
{\color{red} And how to changing colors using NEW CREATED styles or themes?}

\newmenucolortheme{menucores}{HTML}{005500}{00FF00}{00BB00}[550000][FF0000][BB0000]
\newmenustylesimple{menucoresstyle}{}[,]{menucores}
\renewmenumacro\menu[>]{menucoresstyle}

\menu{Extras>Settings>{Units, rulers and origin}}

\keys{\ctrl+C}

\directory{C:/mame/mameroms/indy.rom}

\end{document}



Thank you. And how to change the colors/theme but obtaine each step of the Menu with usual shapes in the previous \menu... ?

@MikaIke isn't that exactly what you achieved below "Changing colors..."?
